# How do I get the month number from the year and week number in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

As the title says, given the year and the week number, how do I get the month number?

edit: if a week crosses two months, I want the month the first day of the week is in.

edit(2): This is how I get the week number:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

I'm just trying to do the reverse.

Comment: The reverse is just not well-defined. The answers below contain some relevant questions, try to answer them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
static int GetMonth(int Year, int Week)
{
    DateTime tDt = new DateTime(Year, 1, 1);

    tDt.AddDays((Week - 1) * 7);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 365; ++i)
    {
        int tWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
            tDt, 
            CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, 
            DayOfWeek.Monday);
        if (tWeek == Week)
            return tDt.Month;

        tDt = tDt.AddDays(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would have preferred something simpler, but it works :)

Answer (score 10):

If you assume that the first day of your definition of week is the same day as the 1st day of the year, then this will work:

```
int year = 2000;
int week = 9;
int month = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(7 * (week - 1)).Month;
```

Obviously, a *true* answer would depend on how you define the first day of the week, and how you define how a week falls into a month when it overlaps more than one.

Comment: If we are talking about an ISO8601 week, then something based on the algorithms in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number would be truer.

Comment: Why would you assume that? You might as well assume that a week is 366 days long. You'd get it right one time out of 52 ;-)

Comment: I *wouldn't* assume that, I would specify the problem completely and then code something that conforms to that specification. Since that wasn't done in the question, I chose the simplest way to solve the underspecified problem that makes sense in a majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it also depend on the day of the week?

Answer (score 2):

this should be able to help

```
 public int getMonth(int weekNum, int year)
 {
     DateTime Current = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
     System.DayOfWeek StartDOW = Current.DayOfWeek;
     int DayOfYear = (weekNum * 7) - 6; //1st day of the week

     if (StartDOW != System.DayOfWeek.Sunday) //means that last week of last year's month
     {
         Current = Current.AddDays(7 - (int)Current.DayOfWeek);
     }
     return Current.AddDays(DayOfYear).Month;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you could face is that most years do not start at the beginning of a week, which shifts everything.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

1. Sunday is the first day of the week.
2. Partial week still counts as week 1
3. Outputs beginning and ending month as integer array.

   ```
   public int[] getMonth(int weekNum, int year)
   {

       DateTime StartYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
       System.DayOfWeek StartDOW = StartYear.DayOfWeek;
       DateTime DayOfYearWeekStart = default(DateTime);
       DateTime DayOfYearWeekEnd = default(DateTime);
       int x = 0;
       if ((StartDOW == System.DayOfWeek.Sunday)) {
           DayOfYearWeekStart = StartYear.AddDays((weekNum - 1) * 7);
           DayOfYearWeekEnd = DayOfYearWeekStart.AddDays(6);
       } else {
           for (x = 0; x <= 7; x += 1) {
               if (StartYear.AddDays(x).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
                   break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
               }
           }

           if (weekNum == 1) {
               DayOfYearWeekStart = StartYear;
               DayOfYearWeekEnd = StartYear.AddDays(x - 1);
           } else if (weekNum > 1) {
               DayOfYearWeekStart = StartYear.AddDays(((weekNum - 2) * 7) + x);
               DayOfYearWeekEnd = DayOfYearWeekStart.AddDays(6);
           }

       }

       int[] Month = new int[2];
       Month[0] = DayOfYearWeekStart.Month;
       Month[1] = DayOfYearWeekEnd.Month;

       return Month;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 3.0 and later you can use the [`ISOWeek`-Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek).

```cs
public static int MonthOfFirstDay(int year, int week)
{
    return ISOWeek.ToDateTime(year, week, DayOfWeek.Monday).Month;
}
```

Note that the year might not fit, as the first week of a year can already start in end of December the year before. For instance the first week of 2020 started on Monday 2019-12-30.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. You need at least the day on which the 1st week starts (or when the week starts), to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Which is defined in CultureInfo

Answer (score 0):

You cant. A week may start in one month and end in another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming that a "week" is any group of 7 sequential days. It isn't. Given Year(2008), Week(5), you could be in either January or Febuary, depending on when your "week" starts.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Calculate the week number according to ISO 8601

    public static int Iso8601WeekNumber(DateTime dt)
    {
            return  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }

// ...

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

// Calculate the WeekOfMonth according to ISO 8601
int weekOfMonth = Iso8601WeekNumber(dt) - Iso8601WeekNumber(dt.AddDays(1 - dt.Day)) + 1;
```