# How do I get the first day in a week Week, Year (gregorian calendar) in C#?

Tags: c#, calendar

I need to calculate the date of the first day in a calendar week given a year/week, e.g.

Week 53 in 2009 -> Mon, 28.12.2009
Week 1 in 2010 -> Mon, 04.01.2010

How would you wirte that code?

PS: In the Gregorian calendar the first week of a year is the first week with 4 days.

Comment: duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number/662547#662547](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number/662547#662547)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do all the calculation yourself, use the `System.Globalization.Calendar` class.  I think you can use the `GetDayOfYear()` method to get what you need.

Check [this MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofyear.aspx) for the example.