# Get Date Range by week number c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In .net, knowing the week number how can I get the weekdays date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854429/in-net-knowing-the-week-number-how-can-i-get-the-weekdays-date)

Hello,

I've got a question for ya'll.
How do i get the date range of a given week number.

For example:
If I enter week 12 the output should be:

```
21-03-2011
22-03-2011
23-03-2011
24-03-2011
25-03-2011
26-03-2011
27-03-2011
```

I really hope you guys can help me out, i just cant find the awnser anywhere!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strong duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854429/in-net-knowing-the-week-number-how-can-i-get-the-weekdays-date

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ## Note
>
> I appear to have missed bug. The current code have been updated as of 2012-01-30 to account for this fact and we now derive the `daysOffset` based on Tuesday which according to [Mikael Svenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153390/mikael-svenson) appears to solve the problem.

These ISO8601 week date calculations are a bit wonky, but this is how you do it:

```
DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(yyyy, 1, 1); 

int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Tuesday - jan1.DayOfWeek; 

DateTime firstMonday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset); 

var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar; 

int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

var weekNum = ww;

if (firstWeek <= 1) 
{ 
    weekNum -= 1; 
}

var result = firstMonday.AddDays(weekNum * 7 + d - 1);

return result;
```

Basically calculate a reference point, then add days, the hard stuff has to do with the fact that week 53 can sometimes occur in January and week 1 can sometimes occur in December. You need to adjust for that and this is one way to do that.

The above code calculates the date off a year (yyyy) and week number (ww) and day of week (d).

Comment: If I enter yyyy=2012, ww=1 and d=Monday(1), your code returns Jan 9th and not Jan 2nd which would be correct.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9064954/153390

Comment: That's unfortunate, I do remember reworking this code and creating a lot of test but this is older and obviously not right, your small change however seem to work and I don't have the ability to test this more thoroughly, so I'm gonna believe that you did that yourself and correct my own answer ;)

Comment: Tested it for every day from 1900-1-1 to 3000-12-31 :)

Answer (score 5):

- Find out which day of the week was the first January of the year (e.g. in 2011 it was Saturday)
- Add the necessary count of days to become the next monday (2 days)
- From this day on, add (Number of weeks - 1) * 7 days to get the first day of the week you are interested in
  -Display this day plus the next  days to get the whole week

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```
        DateTime d = new DateTime(someYear, 1, 1);
        d.AddDays(numWeeks * 7);
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToShortDateString());
            d.AddDays(1);
        }
```

Comment: Won't downvote - but John's solution below is correct. This is all laid out in ISO stuff...

Comment: Yes, this is too simplistic and occasionally computes the wrong date.