# Get List of weeks by giving year and month as parameter C#

Tags: c#

I need list of weeks with starting and ending dates by giving int year and  int month,

Example Result,

Week1 = 7/1/2012 to 7/1/2012

Week2 = 7/2/2012 to 7/8/2012

Week3 = 7/9/2012 to 7/15/2012

Week4 = 7/16/2012 to 7/22/2012

Week5 = 7/23/2012 to 7/29/2012

Week6 = 7/30/2012 to 7/31/2012

Comment: Why does the first week only have one day? Because it's a Sunday? You need to be more precise in your question.

Comment: the 1st week have only 1 day because first day of week is Monday,
its basically the calender view if we see our calender in windows

Comment: Well, obviously he put `July` and `2012` as parameters. Those are weeks of July. What I do not like about this question is that he didn't show any effort to solve it himself...

Comment: @user1500529: Right, you didn't say any of that before though. Bear in mind that different cultures and contexts use different "first day of week" ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// using System.Globalization;
var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
var firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
var weekPeriods =
Enumerable.Range(1, calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month))
          .Select(d =>
          {
              var date = new DateTime(year, month, d);
              var weekNumInYear = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, firstDayOfWeek);
              return new { date, weekNumInYear };
          })
          .GroupBy(x => x.weekNumInYear)
          .Select(x => new { DateFrom = x.First().date, To = x.Last().date })
          .ToList();
```

Of course you can change the `Culture` (here I have used the `CurrentCulture`).

Comment: Thank you so much as its working great. i need one more favour from you. 
can you please also let me know how i will get the result from this var object? 
or is possible save these value in a array from where i can access them easily.
Thankx

Comment: Check my edit. I added a `ToList()` at the end so you get a list of periods :)

Comment: Thank you so much Dear
Specially for list conversion :D

Answer (score 2):

check this one and edit according to your need

```
// Get the weeks in a month

        DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
        // first generate all dates in the month of 'date'
        var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)).Select(n => new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, n));
        // then filter the only the start of weeks
        var weekends = (from d in dates
                       where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                       select d).ToList();
        foreach (var d in weekends)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
        Console.Write(weekends);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

hope it help you.

you can also take a look here for other stuff [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363978/get-a-list-of-weeks-for-a-year-with-dates)