# How to assign linq anonymous type variable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a linq query that gives me an `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(of <Anonymous Type>)`. Actually I wanted to create a class to get better access to what I want form that query but I fail aready with declaring a member variable that should hold the query outcome. The query I use in the Sub New() of my class is (explained and c# version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363978/get-a-list-of-weeks-for-a-year-with-dates):)

```
Dim jan1 = New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)
Dim startOfFirstWeek = jan1.AddDays(1 - CInt(jan1.DayOfWeek))
Dim weeks = Enumerable.Range(0, 54).[Select](Function(i) New With { _
    Key .weekStart = startOfFirstWeek.AddDays(i * 7) _
}).TakeWhile(Function(x) x.weekStart.Year <= jan1.Year).[Select](Function(x) New With { _
    x.weekStart, _
    Key .weekFinish = x.weekStart.AddDays(4) _
}).SkipWhile(Function(x) x.weekFinish < jan1.AddDays(1)).[Select](Function(x, i) New With { _
    x.weekStart, _
    x.weekFinish, _
    Key .weekNum = i + 1 _
})
```

My Class should look like:

```
Public Class WeekInfo

Private _weeks as ?????

end Class
```

Could anyone tell me what is the usual procedure to accomplish that task and how to put the find a type for my member to access the weeks variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.Net [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384767.aspx) are exposed as type Object so you're variable would be:

```
Dim weeks As IEnumerable(Of Object)
```

You will not get intellisense on the anonymous type's fields outside of the function you created them in but you can access them dynamically, i.e.

```
For Each week In weeks
    Console.WriteLine(week.weekStart + " " + week.weekFinish)
Next
```

If you need to expose the type externally you should define a concrete class or struct instead.

Comment: What i did is. I put the query in The constrctor, then i created a member _weeks as IEnumerable(of Object). puttint _weeks = weeks and try to access the _weeks in a property that gives me a Opstict On doesnt allow late binding error. Do you know how i can solve this?

Comment: @ruedi you can only access the properties with Option Strict Off - see [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2890023/2012417), otherwise you'll need to use a concrete type

Comment: if i get that right you have to set Option Strict Off for the whole project in VB.NET but you can use dynamic for a specific variable in c# to set Option Strict Off just that variable? That would be a big + for c# concering working with linq objects!

Comment: @ruedi it appears you can set [Option Strict Off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) on a per file basis

Answer (score 0):

Make your WeekInfo class look like this:
    Public Class WeekInfo

```
    Public Property WeekStart As Date
    Public Property WeekEnd As Date
    Public Property WeekNumber As Int32
End Class
```

And then load it with you linq query as list of your WeekInfo(s):

```
    Dim jan1 = New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)
    Dim startOfFirstWeek = jan1.AddDays(1 - CInt(jan1.DayOfWeek))
    Dim weeks = Enumerable.Range(0, 54).Select(Function(i) New With { _
        Key .weekStart = startOfFirstWeek.AddDays(i * 7) _
    }).TakeWhile(Function(x) x.weekStart.Year <= jan1.Year).[Select](Function(x) New With { _
        x.weekStart, _
        Key .weekFinish = x.weekStart.AddDays(4) _
    }).SkipWhile(Function(x) x.weekFinish < jan1.AddDays(1)).[Select](Function(x, i) New WeekInfo With { _
        .WeekStart = x.weekStart, _
        .WeekEnd = x.weekFinish, _
        .WeekNumber = i + 1 _
    }).ToList()
```