# C# Linq - Group allready grouped data

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I've groupted data which now looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Delivered</td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Sent</td>
    <td>150</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Received</td>
    <td>110</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Delivered</td>
    <td>79</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Sent</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>
```

Here's the code how I get it:

```
var query = await _context.product.AsNoTracking().Where(x => (x.productDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && x.productDate.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date).ToListAsync();

if (query == null) return null;

var data = query.GroupBy(x => x.productStatusId)
           .Select(product => new productsChartDTO
           {    
               Type =
                (
                    product.FirstOrDefault().productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Delivered || product.FirstOrDefault().productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.InProcess ? "Delivered" :
                    product.FirstOrDefault().productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Sent || product.FirstOrDefault().productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.InProcess ? "Sent" :
                    product.FirstOrDefault().productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Received ? "Received" : "Unknown"
                ),
               Amount = product.Sum(x => x.Amount)
           });  
return data;
```

As it's possible to seen guys, even if I grouping by `productStatusId`, if `productStatus` is in '`InProcess`' or in '`Delivered`' there will be Type "`Delivered`", so after this query
I'm seeing results with type "`Delivered`" twice as I posted in example.

I think after this execution I should be grouping data again?

How could I achieve this ?

Is it possible to continue grouping on this query or there should be another one which would group again?

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your logic to the `GroupBy` method and return a type `string` instead of an `int` from it:

```
var data = query
    .GroupBy(x => x.productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Delivered || x.productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.InProcess ? "Delivered" :
                x.productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Sent || x.productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.InProcess ? "Sent" :
                x.productStatusId == (int)Enums.productStatus.Received ? "Received" : "Unknown")
    .Select(product => new productsChartDTO
    {
        Type = product.Key,
        Amount = product.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your generous help!! What if I don't want to return the type 'Unknown'. It exists in the data as a part of the data, but I only want to return other Types than 'Uknown'.
I want to see only 'Delivered', 'Sent', 'Received'. Would that be possible using this approach?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Add a `.Where(g => g.Key != "Unknown")` between the calls to `GroupBy` and `Select`? This should filter out the "Unknown" group.

Comment: you are great man :) yes I did, how come you've learned C# so well? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.GroupBy(x => x.productStatusId)
```

Do

```
.GroupBy(x => {
if (new [] { (int)Enums.productStatus.InProcess, (int)Enums.productStatus.Delivered }.Contains(x.productStatusId) {
  return "Delivered";
} else if ((int)Enums.productStatus.Sent == x.productStatusId) { // Note: your code had 'InProcess' twice
  return "Sent";
} else if ((int)Enums.productStatus.Received == x.productStatusId) {
  return "Received";
}

return "Unknown";
})
```

Comment: o.0 will try it soon1