# Convert calendar-week to Date

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, calendar

is there a simple builtin function that i could use to get a date instance from a calendarweek/year-combination?

It should be possible to enter `10w2005` into a TextBox and i'll create the date `07 March 2005` from it.

Monday should be first day and CalendarWeekRule should be FirstFullWeek.

My first approach was:

```
Dim w As Int32 = 10
Dim y As Int32 = 2005
Dim d As New Date(y, 1, 1)
d = d.AddDays(7 * w)
```

But this does not work because the FirstDay- CalendarWeekRule are not applied.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

this is what i've ended with(Thanks to fjdumont for the link):

```
Public Shared Function FirstDateOfWeek(ByVal year As Integer, ByVal weekOfYear As Integer) As DateTime
      Dim jan1 As New DateTime(year, 1, 1)
      Dim daysOffset As Integer = CInt(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) - CInt(jan1.DayOfWeek)
      Dim firstWeekDay As DateTime = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset)
      Dim curCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
      Dim firstWeek As Integer = curCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
      If firstWeek <= 1 Then
          weekOfYear -= 1
      End If
      Return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number) should help. You will have to parse the string, somewhat like this.

```
string[] spl = input.ToLower().Split("w");
int year = int.Parse(spl[1]);
int week = int.Parse(spl[0]);
```

Comment: So the answer is: there is no simple builtin function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim dfi As Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
    Dim cal As Globalization.Calendar = dfi.Calendar

    '10w2005
    Dim w As Integer = 10 'week
    Dim y As Integer = 2005
    Dim d As DateTime = New DateTime(y, 1, 1)

    If cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday) <> 1 Then
        w -= 1
        d = d.AddDays(8 - d.DayOfWeek)
    End If

    d = d.AddDays(7 * w)
    Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString)
```

Comment: I've added my solution to my question. Thanks anyway.