# Need to calculate date based on year - week - day

Tags: c#, datetime-generation

How can I calculate the date in C# when I recieve the year, weeknumber and day in week. For example:
Year  = 2011
Week = 27
day = 6

result should be 2011-7-10

---

Thanks to all. I solved it based on the wikipedia algorithm.

Comment: For the other way around you have this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0666bawa.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate date from week number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number)

Answer (score 2):

No C# code here (sorry), but assuming that you're talking about ISO week date, you can find a general algorithm that calculates the Gregorian date of an ISO week date in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_a_date_given_the_year.2C_week_number_and_weekday). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 public static DateTime GetDateTime(int year, int week, int day, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        int firstWeek = cultureInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(firstDayOfYear, cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
        int dayOffSet = day - (int)cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + 1;
        return firstDayOfYear.AddDays((week - (firstWeek + 1)) * 7 + dayOffSet + 1);
    }
```

I should point out my implementation is not zero based. (so Year=2011, Week=27, day=6) is july 2nd, 2011.