# Given Year, Month,Day and the Week number, is it possible to get the Date in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number)

Given Year, Month,Day and the Week number, is it possible to get the Date?

```
e.g. Year = 2010
     Month =Jan
     Day = Sun
     WeekNumber = 3
```

output :  **2010-01-10**

I am trying  it in c#

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the Algorithm I described below is coded in the duplicate post.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it like this:

```
        int Year = 2010;
        int Month = 1; //Jan=1, Feb=2, ...
        int Day = 0; //Sun=0, Mon=1, ...
        int WeekNumber = 3; // greater than 0

        DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(Year, Month, 1);            
        int firstDay = (int)dateValue.DayOfWeek;
        dateValue = dateValue.AddDays(Day - firstDay + (WeekNumber - 1) * 7);
```

Comment: For a valid result (((int)dateValue.Month)==Month) must hold

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something for such date calculations in plain .NET BCL. But there are libraries that can help you, see i.e. [Fluent DateTime](http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/). Using this library, you can try something like that:

```
var firstWeekInYearBeginning = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2).Previous(DayOfWeek.Monday); // note 2 to not miss a week if the year begins on Monday
var expectedDate = 3.Weeks().From(firstWeekInYearBeginning);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the APIs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), don't this its possible to initialize a DateTime Object from the information given. You would need to develop an algorithm to get the exact date of the year. A simple strategy would be to get the first Day of the month and based on that, find first Monday of the month. This is the start of WeekNumber 1 for that month, and you can locate your required Week by simpl loop and locate the exact date. You would then know the calendar date you are interested in.

BTW: I am assuming WeekNumber of a year/month starts from the first Monday of that Year/Month. Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out System.Globalization.Calendar class. It might be useful.