# Get the dates for GetWeekOfYear in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0, cultureinfo

I have this function which gives me ( for a current date ) - its week num :

so for  : `DateTime(2009,1,1)`

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(2009,1,1), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday).Dump();
```

answer : `1`

and for   : `DateTime(2009,1,4)`

answer : `2`

[image]

now  , I need a function which gives me the startDate && endDate for this values  :

```
so for week #1 -> 1/1/2009   ---> 1/3/2009
so for week #2 -> 1/4/2009   ---> 1/10/2009
```

Hence : i have a function which gives me the week num for a specified date.
but this week spans from `x---> y`

I need those x and y.

thanks.

*p.s. - i've been searching for a func like this , and didn't find . :-(*

Comment: You want dates of a particular week?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal yes. according to my example  ,week #1 spans from 1..3 ....

Comment: I don't see the problem. Can't you just go from the date back to the previous Sunday / next Saturday, and add a special exception for when that day is in a different year? (Didn't vote.)

Comment: @hvd i dont nees the sundays ! i need this : week number #1 in 2009 starts at 1/1 and ends at 1/3.....week number 2 starts from 1/4 and ends at 1/10...

Comment: @RoyiNamir Maybe I misunderstood, I thought you were starting with a date. "The week of Jan 5 runs from Jan 4 to Jan 10", where you get "Jan 4" by looking for the last Sunday before or on Jan 5, and where you get "Jan 10" by looking for the first Saturday on or after Jan 5.

Comment: @hvd the .net function GetWeekOfYear is right. now i need according to this function result - to calc the dates .

Comment: @RoyiNamir And my approach would be consistent with your use of GetWeekOfYear...

Comment: @hvd sorry... do you understand my desired result ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, I understand your desired output, it's just your input that I'm wondering about. Does your function need to accept a year and week number as input, or is it also okay if it accepts a date as input, as long as the output is correct?

Comment: @hvd  it accepts a date as input ( as cuurently as the .net function does) and it calculates its week num , and by this week num i need its start date and end date....thanks. ( am i clear now ?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're misreading my comments, I'll try once more to be as clear as possible. One answer's function, which gives the wrong result, has signature `DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek)`. If it were to give the right result, would that signature be acceptable, or must it be `DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(int year, int week)`? Either way, the function you ask, `DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(int week)`, cannot be written, because it doesn't know what year to look in.

Comment: @hvd oh... sorry. if it had worked - the signature will be : `GetFirstDayOfWeek(int year, int week)`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I've worked my approach for the first day of the week, does that help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate date from week number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I saw your solution before. it doesnt giv me the desired result. try execute `FirstDateOfWeek(  2009, 15, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay ).Dump();` it gives 4/13/2009 00:00:00... which is wrong. see my edit to the accepted answer. this is the right solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i'll explain : `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(2009,4,8), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday).Dump();` tells me the week number is 15. my function   `GetFirstDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2009,4,8)).Dump();` showes me 04/05/2009 00:00:00 and it is correct. the first day of the week ( not strating monday) is at 04/05/2009 http://www.customcalendarmaker.com/printable/printable-2009-calendar/ ... and the last day of the week is : `GetLAstDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2009,4,8)).Dump();` = 03/13/2009 . so your solution doesnt help me .

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Weeknumbers _and FirstDayOfWeek are very culture dependent. You just failed to specify your problem correctly. Also a good description of input (date or year+week ?) would have been helpful. Cute pictures are no substitute for clear specifications.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , didnt i write in my question the exact sample to where the week begins ? `so for week #1 -> 1/1/2009   ---> 1/3/2009
so for week #2 -> 1/4/2009   ---> 1/10/2009` ?

Comment: And are you only interested in the first 3 weeks of 2009? Then you can hard-code the solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no im interested in ANY datetime value. 2009 was chosen  just by random...

Comment: Duh, really? But then it's a little thin as a spec, don't you think?

Comment: @henk  are you here to help ? I dont understand your comment. sorry.... is there anything wrong with my question / answered code ?

Comment: You ask a lot of questions, that is great but do try to improve the quality. Suppose a googler lands on this page, it will take a lot of time to figure out what your definition of WekkNumber and FirstDayOfWeek is. This question needs specs, not pictures of calendars.

Comment: The issue is how to invert the built-in .NET library call to CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(). In other words, use that as the spec.

Comment: Here is my answer to the puzzle. I think I have an answer that works for all cultures.  I had problems with all the other solutions proposed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553878/how-to-do-i-invert-the-week-returned-from-calendar-getweekofyear-back-to-a-datet/16553879#16553879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first day in the week, by date:

```
static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    var firstDayOfWeek = date.AddDays(-((date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday + 7) % 7));
    if (firstDayOfWeek.Year != date.Year)
        firstDayOfWeek = new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1);
    return firstDayOfWeek;
}
```

The last day of the week works the same way:

```
static DateTime GetLastDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    var lastDayOfWeek = date.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Saturday - date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7);
    if (lastDayOfWeek.Year != date.Year)
        lastDayOfWeek = new DateTime(date.Year, 12, 31);
    return lastDayOfWeek;
}
```

## Royi's addition ( final) :

extension method which gives you all the details ( week details) from a single date :
p.s. first day of week = sunday.

```
   public class DateTimeSpan
    {
        public DateTime WeekStartDate;
        public DateTime WeekEndDate;
        public DateTime MonthStartDate;
        public DateTime MonthEndDate;
        public DateTime YearStartDate;
        public DateTime YearEndDate;
        public int WeekNum;

    }

    public static DateTimeSpan TimeProperties(this DateTime str)
    {
        if (str == null) return null;
        DateTimeSpan dts = new DateTimeSpan();
        dts.WeekNum=     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(str, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        dts.WeekStartDate = GetFirstDayOfWeek(str);
        dts.WeekEndDate = GetLAstDayOfWeek(str);
        dts.MonthStartDate = new DateTime(str.Year, str.Month, 1);
        int numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(str.Year, str.Month);
        DateTime last = new DateTime(str.Year, str.Month, numberOfDays);
        dts.MonthEndDate = last;
        dts.YearStartDate = new DateTime(str.Year, 1, 1);
        numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(str.Year, 12);
        last = new DateTime(str.Year, 12, numberOfDays);
        dts.YearEndDate = last;

        return dts;
    }


    static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        var firstDayOfWeek = date.AddDays(-((date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday + 7) % 7));
        if (firstDayOfWeek.Year != date.Year)
            firstDayOfWeek = new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1);
        return firstDayOfWeek;
    }

    static DateTime GetLAstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        var firstDayOfWeek = date.AddDays(((DayOfWeek.Saturday - date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7));
        if (firstDayOfWeek.Year != date.Year)
            firstDayOfWeek = new DateTime(date.Year, 12, 31);
        return firstDayOfWeek;
    }
```

Comment: Luckily you already dropped the `GetDayInWeek`. I think I got that wrong: it may, on valid input, return a date in week 1 of year Y+1 when you ask for the last week of year Y. I'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

I once used one of the method described in the comments of this post
http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/getting-the-first-date-in-a-week-with-c-sharp

Comment: +1 beat me to the answer. I used same link code in my app which i have pasted in my answer.

Comment: `GetFirstDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2009,1,1),new CultureInfo("en-US")).Dump();`  gives me 28/12/2008 00:00:00 ....its wrong

Comment: why is it wrong ?  the first day of a week starts on a certain date, and weeks can span years.  For such thing, you'll need to implement an exceptional case;  check if the date that is calculated is in the same year.  If it isn't, get the first date of that year.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels did you read my question ? i need this : week number #1 in 2009 starts at 1/1 and ends at 1/3.....week number 2 starts from 1/4 and ends at 1/10...

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public static class FirstDayOfWeekUtility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first day of the week that the specified
    /// date is in using the current culture. 
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek)
    {
        CultureInfo defaultCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        return GetFirstDateOfWeek(dayInWeek, defaultCultureInfo);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first day of the week that the specified date 
    /// is in. 
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dayInWeek, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
        DateTime firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
        while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
            firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);

            return firstDayInWeek;
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetFirstDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2009,1,1),new CultureInfo("en-US")).Dump();`  gives me 28/12/2008 00:00:00 ....its wrong