# Generating a date using the ISOweeknumber, year and dayoftheweek C#

Tags: c#

I would like to generate a date using the ISOweeknumber, year and dayoftheweek in C#; any help or suggestions please? I am still new to C# and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you please add an example?

Comment: So you have something like this: `2004-W53-6` and you want to convert it to `DateTime`?

Comment: The date is being generated like 'week 10, 2016' and i would like to create a function to generate the actual date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate date from week number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number)

Comment: I need to pass three parameters, ISO week, year, dayOfWeek, cannot understand how exactly is being calculated using the function of mikael svenson

Comment: Look in the duplicate I posted the @GEORGEBAXTER answer, I think it should do exactly what you want