# How to get month number by week number and year

Tags: php

I want to find the month number by given year and given week number,
example- if my year: 2017 and week number is: 25 what will be the month.

Comment: @cb0 not tried yet. nothing found any where how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659183/how-do-i-get-the-month-number-from-the-year-and-week-number-in-c   here is the solution but it is in c#

Comment: You also have to have a specific date to get the correct month number. E.g. the 5th week in 2017 is spanning end of Jan and beginning of Feb.

A naive approach would be: Every year has 52 weeks, and every month has 4 weeks. Think about this for a moment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime( "01.01.2017" ); // set datetime to 1, January 2017
$date->modify( "+21 weeks" ); // add 21 weeks
echo $date->format( "m" ); // echo month
```